# Creating a data frame in pandas recursively

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a data frame using pandas that is defined recursively based on it's previous input and a different data frame:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame([average],columns=['Closing Price']) 
k=2/13
i=1
for y in range(0,len(df2)):
    if(len(df1)==1): 
        pre_ema=average
    else:
        pre_ema=df1.iloc[len(df1)-1]
    close=df2.iloc[len(df1)]
    new_ema=(close*k)+(pre_ema*(1-k))
    df3=pd.DataFrame([new_ema],columns=['Closing Price'])
    df1.append(df2)
enter code here
```

The program can calculate what df3 is; however, for some reason it won't append to df1 inside of the loop. If i run df1.append(df2) outside the loop, it gives me what I expect. I can't seem to get it to define itself recursively. Also, all 3 data frames are defined and average is also defined.

Comment: You seem to be missing the assignment, `df1= df1.append(df2)`. Also should `df2` be `df3` (`df3` is unused in the code).

Comment: That worked, thanks. For some reason though I get an indexer is out-of-bounds error when I run the loop. But after I print what the new data frame is, it’s prints out what I was expecting to get as an output. Is the error something I need to be worried about?

Comment: @Shaido          So I have ran into a weird error. I'm using jupyterlab and am also trying to create a python class in a textfile. When I run my exact code in jupyterlab, I get the index out of bounds error I talked about in my previous comment. But if I then print my dataframe in the next line, I get the data frame that I am expecting to get. When I try to use this code in my textfile and run it as a function in jupyterlab, I get the same index outofbounds error but this time the function won't return the data frame I am expecting. I could also paste the code of my entire function if needed.

Comment: I figured out the problem, I added a break statement in the loop once len(df1)==12. I think the loop was messing up since it kept trying to go after my desired limit.